# Java LinkedStack next = head?

Tags: java, stack

So I have this code for Linked Node Stack (in short Linked Stack) and It confuses me very much! I have an exam tomorrow on that and it confuses me a lot! So take a look:

```
class Node<T> {            
    T item;                  // data in node     
    Node<T> next = null;    // successor node 

    Node(T item0, Node<T> next0) { 
        item = item0; next = next0;
    }
}
```

That is easy to understand no problem, we create a class called Node (it's a data structure) which contains an item of type `T` (can be String, Integer etc..) and another `Node` called *next* to indicate the next Node in line. Everything is clear. Off with that!
Now's time for the `Stack` itself, so here's the code:

```
class Stack<T> {

    private Node<T> head = null; // first node (null if empty)

    Stack() {}

    Stack(int n) {}

    boolean isEmpty() {return(head==null);}

    boolean push(T t) { 
        head = new Node<>(t,head); 
        return true; // always space available
    }

    T pop() { 
        if (head==null) return null;
        T t = head.item;
        head = head.next; 
        return t;
    }
}
```

Now here's where I lose my mind! OK so! First off when we initiate the Stack we create a `Node` with name *head* okay! Got it and it's `null` yes! Next, black magic to me is when we use the `push(T t)` method. So we say `head = new Node<>(t, head)` okay okay! slow down there fellow! We replace the existing `null` *head* with a new Node which contains the data *t* and as the *next* node, it carries itself?? so head = data, head(null,null)..? What if we add a 2nd element? it's going to be again head = data, head(data, head(null, null)... ?

Please explain this to me in plain english! :(

Comment: head.next is in fact the previous element in the stack (the element below) . At start head is null, then head is the new added element for which its next member point on the .. previous head.

Comment: head is replaced each time but previous head remains referenced by new Node: for math it is more head[n+1] = new Node<>(t, head[n]) . head[3] = ( data, head[2] ) where head[2] = (data, head[1]) ; head[1] = ( data, null ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
head = new Node<>(t,head);
```

is executed in the order
1) `new Node<>(t,head)`
2) `head = ...`

So when you create the new `Node` object you pass in the old value of `head`, not a reference to itself.

To be less confusing this line can be rewritten as

```
Node<T> oldHead = head;
head = new Node<>(t, oldHead);
```

So when the stack is empty `head = null`
When we add one item `head = (item1, null)`
When we add another item `head = (item2, (item1, null))`

Comment: Ohhhhhh!! Now I get it! Thank you very very very much sir! :D

Answer (score 1):

The `Node` created by `push` does not contain a reference to itself.  When you perform an assignment in Java, the variable being assigned (on the left-hand side of the equal sign) is not altered until **after** everything on the right side is fully resolved and constructed.

Therefore, at the time that Java executes the `Node` constructor to create the new `head` node, the value of `head` within the `Stack` object *still points to the previous head*.  The new Node for `head` is thus created with the new data, plus a reference to the **previous** `head` Node.  Then, only after the new `Node` object is fully created (and has a `next` value pointing to the previous `head`), the value of `head` within the `Stack` object is assigned to the newly-created object.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are over thinking this. So the way a stack works is similar to a linked list. So if you have an empty list, head = null. You got that part right.

So what you are doing when you call push is adding that new node to the top, so it would be the new head node. 
head = new Node<>(t,HEAD);
now the new node is at the top of the list and the second argument of Node (which is HEAD)is pointing to the old node that was the head of the linked list.

so on first push, it isn't hard to understand:
first call to push: head = new node(t, NULL) because the old head node is NULL

second call to push: head = new node(t, head) and head (the second argument here) is pointing to what was the old head and is now the next item on the list

Answer (score 1):

When you do `head = new Node<>(t, head)`, you are updating the head of the stack to a `Node` with `Node.item = t`and `Node.next = oldHead`, which in this case is `null`
 because you haven't put anything in it.

If we add 1 element to an empty stack we get Node(data1,null). If we add a second item to the stack we get Node(data2, Node(data1, null))